# SE Network Login Test Page: "Messaging failed; stackauth.com skipped" - Am I missing something?

Tags: support, bug, status-deferred, login, ssl

While looking for a generic inbox [link](https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox), I stumbled onto the hidden links [page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8211/370758), where a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161054/370758) by [@ShadowWizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859) links to the Network Login [Test Page](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help).

Here's my test result:
[image: img]

SO & SE *seem* to be working properly... or **are there features that I don't know about because they've *never* worked for me?**  ...perhaps notification of new SE [Inbox messages](https://stackoverflow.com/topbar/inbox), so I wouldn't have to use a [plugin](https://stackapps.com/q/3780/50270) to generate notification (while on other sites)?

A search for enabling HTML5 postMessage on Firefox led me to [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), but I'm not enough of a web dev to fully understand how this applies to me.

<sub>I usually use `Firefox 56.0.2/64-bit` on Windows 7, but I got the same result from `Chrome56` & `IE11`.</sub>

Comment: I didn't know about this "Messaging" feature a few minutes ago, but suddenly I need it more than anything else in the world. :-)

Comment: On mobile chrome browser I also fail the same checks you did. Funny.

Comment: On chrome desktop, it also fails

Comment: Speaking as a resident of Houston, I'm tired of hearing about everyone else's problems. ;-)

Comment: Also reproduced with Firefox 59.0.2 on Win10

Comment: @WilliamPrice: Seen occasionally on CA license plate frames: "San Andreas: It's not our fault"

Comment: Same on win 10/chrome 65

Comment: Reproduced in FF 59.0.2 on Arch Linux

Comment: The problem is in the regex used to check if the `message` comes from stackauth domain, it still expects the `http` scheme. And it will then fail an other test in stackauth iframe, because it expects the parent's origin to be `http://stackoverflow`. Replacing [network-login-test-page] with [ssl] since it is actually an ssl update remaining bug.

Comment: And for the ones who want, [here is a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WSembw8H) of the working function that you can paste in your js console from the [test-page](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem on your side, but one in the test-page's code itself.

The code still expects non-secure *http://* scheme in multiple places, and thus fails because of the recent *http**s**://* upgrade SE received.

You can find a *fixed* version of this page's test [on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WSembw8H) that you can paste in your js console from the [test-page](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help) itself, but it will fail later on, since there is an other test executing code from *stackauth* domain, which expects you to come from insecure *http://* scheme.

So all in all, this test's failure doesn't mean you are missing any feature.

Answer (score 7):

This entire test page is... Woefully obsolete. Even if all the tests completed successfully, there's no guarantee you'll be able to log in... And of course, the tests failing indicates nothing, since the tests themselves are broken.

At some point, we'll probably want an up-to-date diagnostics page that reflects the current reality of how login works across various browsers.

Until then, if you find a link to this page anywhere official, report *that* as a bug instead.